# How can i configure swagger3 to support https requests with @SecurityScheme

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, swagger-3.0

I have updated my project to Springboot version 2.6.3 and swagger 3. I need to support authorize HTTPS requests but `@SecurityScheme` supports only https requests. Is there a way to configure `@SecurityScheme` annotation to support https requests or any other solution?

Comment: Do you mean http? Now you're saying you want https, but it only supports https.

Comment: i want it other way around. 
locally I see HTTP and I want to hit from the server with HTTPS, but on server, it is showing HTTP

Answer (score 2):

It is the *server URL* that "dictates" if is to be used *http* or *https*. `Type.HTTP` only refers to the security scheme type. To use *HTTPS* change the *Server URL* to be *https*.

Example:

```
        return new OpenAPI().servers(List.of(new Server()
    .url("https://google.com")))
    .components(new Components()
        .addSecuritySchemes("xpto",
            new SecurityScheme()
                .type(Type.HTTP)));
```